# HTML5 record voice audio and send it via form

Tags: html, forms, audio

I've recently dug into recording audio with HTML5 and the `getUserMedia` interface.
And I have found some examples on how to do that and one example ended up providing a "download" link of the recorded audio that resulted basically in

```
<a href="data:audio/mp3;XVVEEDAD…"
```

So it just embedded the actual audio data in a data link.

Now, I was wondering if I could utilize this and produce something like

```
<form action="…">
  <input type="hidden" name="audio" value="data:audio/mp3;…">
</form>
```

Would a browser be able to handle this?

I'm currently working on an application where people are supposed to answer questions in an interview. They get asked several questions on a page and should be able to answer them in an audio version. This would mean there are several questions on one page and hence several recorders. I'd like to submit the whole data at once.

But my concerns are, that frist of all it's not possible. Secondly if this would be too much data at once?
I'd love to avoid going down the Flash route for this or sending audio data in asynchronous ways, if possible.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer by Ivan, I ended up rewriting the code of the provided article which resulted in my own little tool: https://github.com/icatcher-at/MP3RecorderJS

Comment: For reference, the github repo no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant [this article](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/). Nothing could stop you from trying this method. Instead of

```
var url = 'data:audio/mp3;base64,'+encode64(e.data.buf);
```

in the last code fragment you may use base64 encoded value directly:

```
$('<input>').attr('type','hidden').attr('name','audio').appendTo('form').val(encode64(e.data.buf));
```

Then on server side just decode base64 string to bytes. The finest thing is that you can start with this approach very quickly and test whether it meets your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, absolutely!

First, you need the function to convert a dataURI to a blob object.

```
var dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)]);
};
```

Then, you need a FormData.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('filename_you_want_to_post', dataURItoBlob($('a').attr('href')));
```

Last, send it with jQuery Aajx:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/where/you/post/to",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
});
```

Good luck.